# How to avoid downcasting when using a list of subclass items in Java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, arraylist, downcast

I have an abstract class A and classes B and C. Classes B and C extend A. I need to hold B and C in the list together, say List. However, B and C have unique methods, so not all items in List can be used to invoke certain methods **unless I am downcasting** which is considered to be a design smell.

I need to keep B and C on the same list because I want to sort them based on their shared attributes which I can. Is keeping them on the same list of their parent type and then downcasting a bad design in this situation?

Comment: Since you need a mixed list, you don't really have a choice.

Comment: Yes, it's a design smell, but not every code smell equals to bad code as long as you can find good arguments to support your decision over other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to keep B and C on the same list because I want to sort them based on their shared attributes which I can.

As long as the requirement is to keep the list sorted with mixed types `B`, `C` both extending `A` an to call their non-inherited methods, you have no choice than using the `List<A>` containing all types.

Although I also try to avoid downcasting when possible, it doesn't mean there are situations when it is neither useful nor necessary.

```
for (A item: sortedList) {
    if (item instanceof B) {
        Whatever fieldB = ((B) item).getFieldB();  // using non-inherited method of B
    } else if (item instanceof C) {
         Whatever fieldC = ((C) item).getFieldC();  // using non-inherited method of C
    } else {
         // either only A or anything different that extends A
    }
}
```

As of Java 14 thanks to [JEP 305: Pattern Matching for instanceof](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/305), such thing gets less verbose:

```
for (A item: sortedList) {
    if (item instanceof B b) {
        Whatever fieldB = b.getFieldB();  // using non-inherited method of B
    } else if (item instanceof C c) {
        Whatever fieldC = c.getFieldC();  // using non-inherited method of C
    } else {
        // either only A or anything different that extends A
    }
}
```

Comment: May want to make it explicit that pattern matching is currently a [preview feature](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/12) and requires the `--enable-preview` switch to use.

Comment: I'm sorry, what?